# why my password isn't changed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change password that saved in db,but my code dose not work. what is wrong? I always see the last message:

> `unable to connect database`

```
public partial class pws : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static string strcon = (System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["strcon"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void ShowPopUpMsg(string msg)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("alert('");
        sb.Append(msg.Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "").Replace("'", "\\'"));
        sb.Append("');");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "showalert", sb.ToString(), true);
    }
    protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            db.Open();
            string strId = string.Empty;
            string strusername = string.Empty;
            string OLdpassword = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand cmd;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE login_username =@login_username ", db);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("login_username", txtOldUsername.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Dispose();
            cmd = null;
            db.Close();
            db.Open();
            SqlDataReader DR;
            DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (DR.Read())
            {
                strId = DR["login_id"].ToString();
                strusername = DR["login_username"].ToString();
                OLdpassword = DR["login_Password"].ToString();
            }
            db.Close();
            if (OLdpassword == txtOldPass.Text)
            {
                db.Open();
                string Command = "Update login Set login_Password= @login_Password WHERE login_username=@login_username";
                SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(Command, db);
                cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login_Password ", txtNewPass.Text);
                cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login_username ", txtOldUsername.Text);
                cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmdIns.Parameters.Clear();
                cmdIns.Dispose();
                cmdIns = null;
                db.Close();
                ShowPopUpMsg("successful");
            }
            else
            {
                ShowPopUpMsg(" old pass is not correct");
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            ShowPopUpMsg("unable to connect database");               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like there is an exception in your try block. Check the StackTrace and fix that exception.

Comment: The error message could be misleading (the chance is quite high). Try to debug the application (F5 should work in your case), put a breakpoint directly behind the "try" and look what line REALLY causes the problem.
If you cannot debug the code: remove try/catch for testing to get the line (and the real error)

Comment: "what is wrong" - how should we know? You're catching all exceptions, *ignoring* the data they contain and just substituting a vague error message.

Comment: Best thing to do is debug your program, but a `break point` on all the important parts of your code to see where the exception is happening

Comment: try never use the `catch` block by suppressing all error messages, change `catch` with `catch (Exception ex)` and the pop up message, do: `ShowPopUpMsg("unable to connect database: " + ex.Message);`. This way you will get the *why* as well.

Comment: One obvious error (and I'm not sure what you *intended* to do) is that there's `cmd = null` followed by a `cmd.ExecuteReader()` with no intervening attempt to assign a new object to `cmd`. Whether that's the only error, I don't know.

Comment: I tried the break point...but that shown me any ERROR. :(

Comment: remove global try/catch block and split it into smaller parts.

Comment: Step through the Code after the Breakpoint (F10) In addition: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right. That is at LEAST ONE error that happens there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this part:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Dispose();
cmd = null;
db.Close();
db.Open();
SqlDataReader DR;
DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

why do you execute a non query, which is a query (select * from ...)?
why do you dispose the SqlCommand object `cmd` and why do you reuse it after disposing?
why do you close and open the line below?

I would rewrite those lines it like this:

```
SqlDataReader DR = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I would recomment a using statement or closing the connection in a finally block:

```
SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(strcon);
try{
    db.Open();
    //.... the rest
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ShowPopUpMsg("unable to connect database: " + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    db.Close();
}
```

and another thing: I would use the primary key in the update statement. `where id = login_id` instead of the username. unless the username is set to "unique"

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you can connect to the database using your credentials and database management tool (I assume you you use MS SQL Server so use MS SQL Server Management Studio)
2. Check if the format of your connection string is correct. You can use this website http://www.connectionstrings.com/ to do it.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to step through the code and find where the exception occures, and look at the details of the exception.

My guess is that there are something wrong with you connection string (strcon).